# VBA parsing through data

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file with a column with rows in the following format:

> {'gender': 'Male', 'national.': 'GBR', 'doc_type': 'passport',
>   'expiry': '2012-02-12', 'issuer': 'GBR'}

I would like to parse through the rows, say A1:A7, to extract it as a meaningful data like that, splitting it into multiple columns.

```
 A         B           C               D               E   
Gender   Nat         Doc_T           Date of Expiry   Issuer
Male     GBR         Passport       2012-02-12     GBR
Male     GBR         Passport       2012-02-12     GBR
Male     GBR         Passport       2012-02-12     GBR
```

I made a head start and wrote this code, however it piles all the data into one cell, I'm not sure how to split it further as above. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  Sub test3()
  Dim rng1 As Range
  Dim c As Range
  Set rng1 = Range("A1:A7")

  For Each c In rng1
   For Each e In Split(Replace(Replace(Replace(c, "'", ""), "{", ""), "}", ""), ",")
        x = Split(e, ":")
        temp = x(0): x(0) = x(1): x(1) = temp
        c.Value = c.Value & vbLf & Application.Trim(Join(x, " "))
    Next
  Next c
```

Produced Ouput with my code:

```
Male gender
GBRnationality
passport document_type
2012-02-12 date_of_expiry
GBR issuing_country
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: There's a library you can use for this:  https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since these entries are JSON strings, I would use a Json Parser.
One that I like is by [(c) Tim Hall](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON)

Then the code becomes:

```
Option Explicit
Sub parseJsonLine()
    Dim JSON As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rSrc As Range, c As Range, r As Range
    Dim v, J As Long, O As Object

Set ws = Worksheets("sheet2")
With ws
    .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(1, 20)).EntireColumn.Clear
    Set rSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

For Each c In rSrc
    Set JSON = parsejson(c.Value2)
    If ws.Cells(1, 2).Value2 = "" Then
        v = JSON.Keys
        Set r = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 2), ws.Cells(1, UBound(v) + 2))
        r.Value2 = v
    End If
    J = 1
    For Each v In JSON
        J = J + 1
        c(2, J) = JSON(v)
    Next v
Next c

End Sub
```

And the results:

[image]

I put the results starting in Column B, but you could overwrite, or put them on a different worksheet, by changing some of the variables in the code.

Answer (score 1):

1. Strip off the brackets `{}`
2. Split by `,` to get the data pairs into an array `DataPairs`.
3. Loop through that array and split each data pair by `:`.
4. Finally strip off the `''` of the data and write it into the cells.

So something like this should work:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ParseData()
    Dim RawData As String
    RawData = "{'gender': 'Male', 'nationality': 'GBR', 'document_type': 'passport', 'date_of_expiry': '2012-02-12', 'issuing_country': 'GBR'}"

    Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
    Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim NextFreeRow As Long
    NextFreeRow = wsOutput.Cells(wsOutput.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    'strip off {}
    RawData = Mid$(RawData, 2, Len(RawData) - 2)

    Dim DataPairs() As String
    DataPairs = Split(RawData, ", ")

    Dim iPair As Long
    For iPair = LBound(DataPairs) To UBound(DataPairs)
        Dim FieldData() As String
        FieldData = Split(DataPairs(iPair), ": ")

        wsOutput.Cells(NextFreeRow, iPair + 1).Value = Mid$(FieldData(1), 2, Len(FieldData(1)) - 2) 'strip of '' and write to cell
    Next iPair
End Sub
```

[image]

Finally you will figure out how to get the headlines too.

Comment: HI, thanks, this works smoothly, I'm struggling to loop it, through say A1:A10. How would I do that? What I added:

I set RawData like below:
    RawData = Cells(i, 1).Value

And then I do 
i = i  + 1 inside of the loop, but it's returning gibberish :(

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something along these lines:

```
Sub TestParseString()

Dim s As String

s = "{'gender': 'Male', 'nationality': 'GBR', 'document_type': 'passport', 'date_of_expiry': '2012-02-12', 'issuing_country': 'GBR'}"

ParseString s, Range("a1"), True
ParseString s, Range("a2")

End Sub

Sub ParseString(strInput As String, rngOutput As Range, _
                Optional blnHeaders = False)

Dim s2 As String
Dim a() As String
Dim l As Long

strInput = Replace(Replace(strInput, "{", ""), "}", "")
a = Split(strInput, ",")

For l = 0 To UBound(a)

    If blnHeaders Then
        s2 = Trim(Replace(Split(a(l), ":")(0), "'", ""))
        rngOutput.Offset(0, l).value = s2
    End If

    s2 = Trim(Replace(Split(a(l), ":")(1), "'", ""))
    rngOutput.Offset(Abs(blnHeaders), l).value = s2

Next l


End Sub
```